# How to add Swipe Gesture on a view that has a Pan Gesture as well?

Tags: swift

So I have a view with a carousel that has two views in it. I have two buttons that navigate from the two views inside the carousel. When the user is on the right view, the right button is disabled and left is enabled. When the user is on the left view, the left button is disabled and right is enabled.

However, I have a Pan gesture that allows the user to also swipe in between the two pages without using the buttons.

When I use the gesture to move in between the two views, I also need the buttons to reflect the change (either be enabled or disabled), however, when I put it on my pan gesture function it doesn't work 100% of the time as a half swipe or short swipe not strong enough to shift the pages but is strong enough to disable/enable my buttons as if the view has changed even though it hasn't.

I tried incorporating a Handle Swipe but I couldn't get the function to work.

Can anyone take a look at this code and let me know if anything is missing? Or better yet, if there is an easier solution to accomplish my goal

```
    @objc func yesswiped (recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        print("swipe pls")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setNavigationBar()


        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yesswiped))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yesswiped))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}
```

Comment: Note: I also have a pan gesture in this view.

Comment: You should fix the pan gesture's triggering of the button enable/disable instead of adding a swipe gesture. Also what are you using for the carousel? Libraries that implement carousels usually have a delegate to tell you that it changed items.